# How can I change the color of the primary sidebar's outline in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I make the outline around the Explorer View a different color?
[outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZlEK.png)

Here is my .vscode/settings.json file:

```json
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "tab.activeBorderTop": "#fc7c05",
        "statusBar.background": "#85410165",
        "activityBar.activeBorder": "#fc7c05",
        "statusBarItem.remoteBackground": "#fc7c05",
        "terminal.tab.activeBorder": "#fc7c05",
        "activityBarBadge.background": "#fc7c05",
        "menu.selectionBackground": "#ff7b0074",
        "list.focusAndSelectionOutline": "#fc7c05",
        "list.activeSelectionBackground": "#803f0243"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the colour customization point you're looking for is `focusBorder`. Note that that's for borders/outlines of things that are focused in general, so it's going to affect more than just the primary sidebar.

You might also be interested in `sideBar.border` and `sideBarSectionHeader.border`, but I don't think those are the ones for what you've shown in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

## UPDATE

I found out what it is, it's `focusBorder`.

Comment: why... did you post this instead of accepting the other answer that I already posted that says exactly this?